# Architecture Restful API using Rails and Devise.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

Hello I have a very noob question about Restful architecture. I am creating an API with Rails and Ember.js in frontend. In my backend I am using Rails and devise. My APP have users, which can register, login...
I would like to use my API as webservice, but it don't have API_KEY or whichever, therefore everybody could use this. If I will add API_KEY, I should have an API_KEY in my ember.js, therefore everybody could see this and use this. So it would be as before.

How should I add security? Any secure example?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `ember-auth`.

http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs

https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth